# Desktop environment alternatives for laptops

Tags: software-recommendation, laptop, desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What different DE's and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-des-and-shells-are-available)

Which desktop environments are better to install in a laptop? . I'm looking for customisation, high performance, good use of space, ...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-des-and-shells-are-available

Comment: The word Best, suggests an opinion, which there is no answer for, because everyone has there own.

Comment: When I refer to good use of space is in case of laptops with a small screen. For example, the windows distribution is essential in a laptop and must have a good way for no waste space.

Comment: As it is, this question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve **facts**, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely **solicit opinion**, **debate** and **extended discussion**. As such, I'm going to close as a duplicate of the one above, since thats about as much help we can give you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say, it depends on the Specs of the Laptop and how you intent to interact with it, and that the "Best" is a subjective thing derived from the experience you will have with these Environments.

- Customization: All of the DEs are customizable. Unity, Gnome Shell, KDE,
  XFCE, LXDE, Openbox, FLuxbox, Razor-qt, Awesome WM, E17, Mate,
  Cinnamon.. all of them are. You can add Panels, launchers, applets, indicators, you have a notification area, etc.
- High performance: LXDE, XFCE, Awesome, E17, Fluxbox, Openbox &
  Razor-qt are the lightest. LXDE uses ~180Mb of RAM and so does E17. the less fancier they are the lighter they are.
- Good use of space: I've no idea what you mean by that. Since pretty much all of them use Panels, you can Hide and auto hide said panels.